# How do I push value into Angular defined variable from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, angular, typescript

I am writing an Angular 4 application, and I am getting back some JSON based upon an *id* value to a PHP script. I would think that with my code, I have a value being passed into ***this.PropertiesList*** below:

```
examineProperties(id) {
    let currentTestIDToFindProperties = this.testScheduleSet[id];
    this.allProperty = this.httpClient.get(this.currentTestIDToFindPropertiesUrl + "?testID=" + currentTestIDToFindProperties.value).subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.testPropertiesList = data;
        console.log("List",this.testPropertiesList);
    });
    console.log("List After Loop",this.testPropertiesList);
}
```

I'm not exactly certain why, but I am getting a response where the console.log for "List After Loop" shows up **before** the "List" console.log, and shows up as *undefined*, as follows:

[image]

How do you have **this.testPropertiesList** persist outside of the **subscribe** function? Why is it that the "List After Loop" is showing up in the console before "List"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with **[async programming](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript)**  you cannot pause the execution of the code and your subscription will be resolved in future but you cannot predict when.  `console.log()` outside the `subscribe` is executed before your subscription is resolved that's why it's undefined
  and `console.log()` inside subscribe call back is invoked when only subscription is resolved.
Refer **[this](https://developer.telerik.com/topics/web-development/introduction-observables-angular-developers/)** for better understanding.